# Firefox: How do I get an nsIMessageManager instance from a JS Module under Electrolysis (e10s)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, multiprocessing

I'm trying to port my Firefox extension to work under Electrolysis / e10s / multi-process mode.  I've got a feature that requires registration through nsIComponentRegistrar so it's in a JSM which gets loaded only once (per process).  I'm running in the child scope, so I don't have access to things like files, but my feature requires that.  So I want to `sendSyncMessage()` to the parent process to fetch that detail (just the path to a file in this case).

[The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/The_message_manager#Loading_scripts_per_child_process) even mention doing something like this explicitly.  But in the JSM I don't have a message manager in scope to call `sendSyncMessage()` on.  How do I get a handle to (the right?) one?  When I get called I don't have anything relating to the content document/window in scope.

---

Update, for clarity:

```
var c = Cc['@mozilla.org/childprocessmessagemanager;1'];
var s = c.getService(Ci.nsISyncMessageSender);
var response = s.sendSyncMessage('id', {'data': 'x'});
dump('response len?? ' + response.length + '\n');
```

This code produces 0 responses, even running directly in the frame script (not in the JSM which the frame script loads).  If I just use the globally available `sendSyncMessage()` in the frame script then it gets the 1 response I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"@mozilla.org/childprocessmessagemanager;1"` is the way to go. Use that in child process JSMs.

However, as MDN puts it:

> In addition to Message Managers centered around window and tab objects
>   there also is a separate hierachy focusing on process boundaries.

Therefore, you cannot use the regular frame script messengers, but have to use `"@mozilla.org/parentprocessmessagemanager;1"` in the parent (main) process.

`child.jsm`

```
let cpmm = Cc["@mozilla.org/childprocessmessagemanager;1"].
           getService(Ci.nsISyncMessageSender);
cpmm.sendSyncMessage("addon:present?!")[0] === "yup"
```

`parent.jsm`

```
let ppmm = Cc["@mozilla.org/parentprocessmessagemanager;1"].
           getService(Ci.nsIMessageListenerManager);
ppmm.addMessageListener("addon:present?", m => "yup");
```

Core code uses this scheme in various places, e.g. [`Network:SampleRate`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?string=NetworkStats%3ASampleRate)

Comment: Use how?  If I substitute `parentprocessmessagemanager` for `childprocessmessagemanager` into the code edited into my question above, I just get `(NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.getService]`.

Comment: The main process should use `parentprocessmanager` and child processes should use `chiildprocessmanaager`. Added an example and hopefully clarified my answer.

Comment: Aha!  I already had a `@mozilla.org/globalmessagemanager;1` calling `addMessageListener()`, which worked for everything else I've done.  For this case it has to be `parentprocessmessagemanager` calling `addMessageListener()` and then finally it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This may work, no promises.

Try loading:

```
Cc["@mozilla.org/globalmessagemanager;1"].getService(Ci.nsIMessageListenerManager);
```

If that doesn't work then try using:

```
Cc['@mozilla.org/childprocessmessagemanager;1'].getService(Ci.nsISyncMessageSender);
```

Or vice-versa

Comment: First/global: Component returned failure code: 0x80570016 (NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.getService] .  Second: doesn't raise anything, but also doesn't pass the message (the listener never gets called; it does work if I call directly from a frame script).

Comment: hmm that's odd, according to [the docs for  nsISyncMessageSender](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsISyncMessageSender) there should be an error thrown if a receiver is not found.

Comment: Yep confusing; if I use that code literally in the frame script it also fails (runs successfully, but produces no results).  If I just use the global `sendSyncMessage()` from the frame script, the listener runs and its result is returned.

Comment: you might want to ping Mossop on irc.mozilla.org about this